# How to add a table to my preexisting database using laravel?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

Hi guys I am new to laravel.
I just started my project for a login
I create a project and made a successful login using the command `php artisan make:auth`.

Now i am trying to create a comment system.I want guide to create it.
Please tell me how can i send the data with a button from the `textarea` to a new table in my preexisting database and to receive that data to my 
commentarea.

Thank you

Comment: so when user press the button, a new table is created and data is inserted to it?

Comment: @Sachith you are correct.

Comment: why creating a new table for each comment? can't you use a table for comment?

Comment: @Sachith yes thats what i need a single table which contains all the comments

Comment: then first create a table for comments with `user_id`,`comment`, etc. then insert comment textarea data to it

Comment: @Sachith Please give a brief answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123111/discussion-between-conor-and-sachith).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a migration using `php artisan make:migration <name of the file>`. For eg. i am using name of the file as conor.
- `php artisan make:migration conor`
- open your `conor.php` file in `databse/migrations`
- In the `up()` function you can see there is an already created `Schema::create`
- In it you can also see `$table->increments('id');` something like this also
- Just keep adding `$table->`+`<name of the tabel structure>`+`('<name of the column>');`
- Just before `php artisan serve` do an one time `php artisan migrate` to register the table